# Why “help” doesn’t show all available Windows commands?

Tags: windows, command-line

I’m trying to understand how the commands are grouped in the Windows command line. I can not find all of them when I type `help`. Why there isn’t eg. the `net` command, and no explanation of what are the signs `> <| &` etc.

I found the official documentation on the [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx#), where all commands are listed alphabetically but I wonder why some of them are not available directly from the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`help` only shows the most essential and most commonly used commands, because if you want to list all possible commands you'll have to display all the executable files in `%PATH%` on your computer which is impractical. System32 and SysWOW64 alone have thousands of *.exe files, and that's not including *.vbs, *.bat, *.cmd, *.msc, *.cpl, *.com... and other extensions in `%PATHEXT%`. If you type `help` on other OSes the same thing will happen

Most of the commands in `help` output are [*internal commands*](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) which are small common facilities or commands for things that can't be done by an external executable file (like `cd`)

> An internal command is an MS-DOS command that is stored in the system memory and loaded from the command.com or cmd.exe. The illustration shows how commands contained within command.com are part of the command.com file. However, with the external commands, each of the commands are their own separate file.
>
> http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/intecomm.htm

Other bigger tools are generally put in separate *.exe files so that they don't consume memory when not needed. In this case `net` is a utility in `System32`. Just open a command prompt and type `where net` and you'll know

```
C:\>where net
C:\Windows\System32\net.exe
```

For symbols like `> <| &` then they're not commands so they can't be put in `help`'s output. You need to read about them in [command redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)